# Uncss Ignore option isn't working

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, uncss

I'm trying remove the css with [uncss](https://github.com/addyosmani/grunt-uncss) but it's removing all the styles no matter if they are listed on the **ignore** array.

The 2 files that I want to compare are just the index and the app.min.js which contains all the templates embedded in the javascript as strings, which are configured using [$templateCache](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache)

take a look to the grunt task maybe there is something obvious that I'm missing:

```
uncss:{
    production: {
        options: {
            ignore: ['.someclass', '.someclass', '.someclass','.etc_etc_class'],
            stylesheets:['app.min.css']
        },
        files: {
            'dist/app.min.css':['dist/index.html','dist/app.min.js']
        }        
    }
}
```

any comment will be more than welcome!

Answer (score 0):

The stylesheets option should have the full path of the css files relative to the root directory. So if the file is in dist/ add that to the stylesheets option.

For example:

```
uncss: {
  dist: {
    options: {
      ignore       : ['#added_at_runtime', /test\-[0-9]+/],
      media        : ['(min-width: 700px) handheld and (orientation: landscape)'],
      raw          : 'h1 { color: green }',
      stylesheets  : ['lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css', 'src/public/css/main.css'],
      ignoreSheets : [/fonts.googleapis/],
      urls         : ['http://localhost:3000/mypage', '...'], // Deprecated
      timeout      : 1000,
      htmlroot     : 'public',
      report       : 'min'
    },
    files: {
      'dist/css/tidy.css': ['app/index.html', 'app/about.html']
    }
  }
}
```

See: https://github.com/addyosmani/grunt-uncss

Comment: My problem is that ignoreSheets is not working. I'm trying to ignore index.css, and my ignoreSheets line looks like this: `ignoreSheets : [/index/],`. But it does nothing. Path shouldn't matter, because it's just matching the word "index".